# How to define alternating elements in XML with XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to define two elements in my XSD-file that can occure 'unbounded' many time, but they have to come always one after another. Example:

XML-File:

```
<company/>
<address/>
<customer/>
<customerContact/>
<customer/>
<customerContact/>
<customer/>
<customerContact/>
```

Now the problem is, that the following XSD definition

```
<xs:element name="company" type="companyType"/>
<xs:element name="address" type="addressType"/>
<xs:element name="customer" type="customerType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:element name="customerContact" type="customerContactType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

is only working with XML files like

```
<company/>
<address/>
<customer/>
<customer/>
<customer/>
<customerContact/>
<customerContact/>
<customerContact/>
```

where *customer* and *customerContact* do not alternate. I had the idea of defining an element which says *customer* **or** *customerContact* and allow repetition of that element. That would solve my problem, but it would also allow other solutions which should not be accepted as valid.

I think the clean solution would be to have XML like

```
<company/>
<address/>
<customerEnvelope>
    <customer/>
    <customerContact/>
<customerEnvelope>
<customerEnvelope>
    <customer/>
    <customerContact/>
</customerEnvelope>
```

and repeat *customerEnvelope*. Unfortunately the XML-structure is already given by my customer, so I am not able to make changes here.

Is it possible to define this kind of structure with XSD, or would I need to use the above-mentioned work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xs:element name="company" type="companyType"/>
<xs:element name="address" type="addressType"/>
<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:element name="customer" type="customerType"/>
  <xs:element name="customerContact" type="customerContactType"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Comment: That was a really simple solution - sometimes the most obvious things are the most diffcult. Thank you very much @13ren!

Comment: @MathiasBader thanks, XSD is quite nice in some ways. BTW: you can think of it like the regex `ab(cd)*`